# Keydown and keyup for existing function

Tags: javascript, keypress

Currently I have buttons to control a rover. One for example is called "forward" and when pressed down accelerates, but when released stops the rover again. Now I want to implement a control of the rover via keypress. So e.g. "w" should accelerate on keydown and stop on keyup.
The sites i have found so far do not show how to include my already existing function in a JS for keydown and keyup. I can not code well enough to figure that out myself. They only show how to print a message when key is pressed.
Can somebody help me out here?

**EDIT: Code and solution can be found in the answer below**

EDIT2: Solution with my edit for keys is right here

```
function functForward{
    var myRPM = document.getElementById('slider').value;
    var myAng = document.getElementById('slider2').value;

    //functForward code
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      var request = "?drive=1" + "&rpm=" + myRPM + "&ang=" + myAng;
      console.log(request);
      xhttp.open("GET", request, true);
      xhttp.send();
}

function functStopDrive(){
    var myRPM = document.getElementById('slider').value;
    var myAng = document.getElementById('slider2').value;

    //funcstopdrive code
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      var request = "?drive=0" + "&rpm=" + myRPM + "&ang=" + myAng;
      console.log(request);
      xhttp.open("GET", request, true);
      xhttp.send();
}

var addEvent = document.addEventListener ? function(target, type, action) {
  if (target) {
    target.addEventListener(type, action, false);
  }
} : function(target, type, action) {
  if (target) {
    target.attachEvent('on' + type, action, false);
  }
}

addEvent(document, 'keydown', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key === 87) {
    functForward();
  }
});
addEvent(document, 'keyup', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key === 87) {
    functStopDrive();
  }
});

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"> 
</script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<button id="Forward" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" 
ng-mousedown="functForward();" ng-mouseup="functStopDrive();">Forward</button>
</div>

<div id="slidecontainer">
 <input type="range" ng-model="myRPM" min="0" max="8000" id="slider" step="500">

 <input type="range" ng-model="myAng" min="-60" max="60" id="slider2" step="5">
</div>
```

Comment: 2 small side notes: why use `XMLHttpRequest` instead of Angular http service? Also, snippets are useful when the code actually runs, if you can't produce a verifiable exemple, it's a bit pointless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use functions `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` attached to the `document` Object.

**Edit 1**

I have edited the answer to break the functions out to be separate from the key listeners so that they are accessable from the button.

**Edit 2**

First, I would make the sliders have `id`s not just `class`es, as this will make it easier for you to parse.

Instead of passing the values into the functions as you have done, I recommend asking the `DOM` for the values each time the function runs, as I have edited to code below to do:

```js
function functforward{
        var myRPM = document.getElementById('slider').value;
        var myAng = document.getElementById('slider2').value;

        //funcforward code
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
          };
          var request = "?drive=1" + "&rpm=" + myRPM + "&ang=" + myAng;
          console.log(request);
          xhttp.open("GET", request, true);
          xhttp.send();
}

function functStopDrive(){
        var myRPM = document.getElementById('slider').value;
        var myAng = document.getElementById('slider2').value;

        //funcstopdrive code
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
          };
          var request = "?drive=0" + "&rpm=" + myRPM + "&ang=" + myAng;
          console.log(request);
          xhttp.open("GET", request, true);
          xhttp.send();
}

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if(e.key == 81){
         functForward();
    }
}

document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    if(e.key == 81){
        functStopDrive();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <button id="Forward" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" ng-mousedown="functForward();" ng-mouseup="functStopDrive();">Forward</button>
</div>

<div id="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" ng-model="myRPM" min="0" max="8000" id="slider" 
step="500">

  <input type="range" ng-model="myAng" min="-60" max="60" 
id="slider2" step="5">
</div>
```

Comment: I need the scope part to get the variable from the Button. The Button is again linked to two sliders that control RPM of the Motors and the Angle of the Actuators. Is there a way to keep those variables? I edited the code above to show how I use scope.

Comment: @Zen_Master Can you post the code for the sliders as well?

Comment: I have added the sliders in their simplest form. I am sorry, but the whole Pythonserver and the Frontend (JS,HTML) are pretty big and I have tried to only use the necessary parts. And failed. So basically the "Forward" button uses the sliders values for "myRPM" and "myAng" in the functions. All that works well with scope and it gets sent back to the Pythonserver via xmlhttp. But now I want to add keys to complement the buttons

Comment: Yes, I have implemented that into my code now. However there are still two issues. The Forward button will only produce 
"GET /?drive=0&rpm=[object%20HTMLInputElement]&ang=[object%20HTMLInputElement]". So it is not properly getting the slider values.
Further the key is not responding at all when pressed.
Do you know why this happens?

Comment: @Zen_Master I have updated the answer with the .value attribute. Does the request complete successfully?

Comment: Yes, thank you! It works perfectly. I have edited your answer to include working buttons. So now the "w" will trigger functForward on pressing and functStopDrive on releasing.

Comment: There is still an issue I have to solve. Pressing and holding down "w" is supposed to keep the rover driving. But it will trigger and stagger functForward multiple times while pressing. Releasing then does not stop it, because it will keep sending functForward for a few more seconds. I have to make it send only once on keydown. But I guess i will open another question if I can't solve it, because it does not have much to do with this particular question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: My edit was denied. I instead edited my question to include the changes I made since.

Comment: Great to hear. As you found the answer useful, would you mind upvoting  it?

Comment: I already did, but since my reputation is to low it will not display it. It registered it, however.